# How can I override twitter-bootstrap on one of the component in Angular 4

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, angular

I am very new at Angular 4. Apologize for my very basic question.
What I am trying to do, is changing the background color of body element of a particular component. 
in the component declaration Material View I have the following:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-material-view',
  templateUrl: './material-view.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./material-view.component.css'],
  providers: [GetDataService]
})
```

and in the material-view.component.css file I put the following line:

```
body{
  background-color: cadetblue !important;
}
```

The problem is the background color is not changed. 
When I inspect the element in the chrome debugger tool, I see that the css is overwritten by tweeter bootstrap. I would expect the css in the component declaration is the most immediate css to be applied to that component. But it seems that I was wrong.
I am not sure why.
Any hint on that is very much appreciated.

Comment: Do you have defined body element inside this component? Because the component specific style file only affects the elements which are created within related html.

Comment: No I haven't created that. I didn't know. So I should create body element in that component? Is that okey I create body with out heah and html tag elements ? Or do I need those tags in as well

Comment: No, you definitely should not create body element anywhere else than your index.html file. If you want to change body color you should try some other technic. But could you explain what exactly are you trying to achieve? Maybe there is some better/easier practice.

Comment: I want to change the back ground color of the page that holds material view component. and only that page no the any where else in the application

Comment: For quick solution you can getElement by Id or sth in material view component onInit or constructor and set it's style there. ... setAttribute("style", "background-color: cadetblue !important;")

Comment: thank you , I kind of get what you are saying I am not sure how to apply it. because I can't use getElementByTagname in onInit. But that was a good hint I will search more to find a way. Thank you

Comment: You can do document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].style = "background-color: cadetblue !important;"

getElementByTagName always returns array so you need [0] even though for body there is one node.